# Why there is a sorting mechanism in std::map?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

I want to use `std::map` as a key/value pair and I want to keep the order in which these key/values pairs have been inserted.
When I print my values, the order rearranged somehow. Below is my code

```
string removeDuplicates(string& s)
{
    // string& s = "asdasdasd"
    map<char, int> duplicates;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        duplicates[s[i]]++;
    }
    map<char, int>::iterator itr = duplicates.begin();
    string result;
    while (itr != duplicates.end())
    {
        result += itr->first;
        itr++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I inserted `"asdasd"` and I expected `"asd"` but the result was `"ads"`

Comment: `std::map` sorts the keys based on the `<` operator. If you want to keep the order, then you'll likely want to use a `std::vector` or something, but you'd have to do your own bookkeeping to remove duplicates.

Comment: You may want to look at boost::MultiIndex https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

Comment: Is there any way to manually change `<` operator like `std::set`. For example, makes it return false for all the values to make them in the same order

Comment: @user9083221 You _could_, but it would cause too much trouble to be worth it. You should consider using a different container.

Comment: `std::map` must be sorted to work.  It's generally implemented as some kind of binary search tree, so sortedness is intrinsic to the data structure.

Comment: You cannot. Sorry. You need to keep two separate data structures, one with keys arranged for easy lookup, and the other arranged in order of insertion.

Comment: You can use a degenerate comparison operator but this will result in degenerate performance. You are better off with a simple vector and a linear search.

Comment: How would you go about implementing a container that has efficient key→value lookup and that keeps insertion order? It's not obvious to me how you do better than an unordered map with an extra vector of keys or something.

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature, not a bug. It's the way that `std::map` is designed  -- a traversal of the red-black tree on which the map is based is always in the order of the map's key.

You might be tempted to try `std::unordered_map`, but you won't get the results you want. This will be traversed in an order you might as well call 'random'.

If you want to preserve the original order of the characters appearing in a string, you will have to do it yourself. But you can do that and build your result string at the same time:

```
string removeDuplicatesKeepingOriginalOrder(string const& s)
{
    // string& s = "asdasdasd"
    string result;
    std::map<char, int> index;
    auto si = s.begin();
    auto se =s.end();
    while (si!=se)
    {
       auto f = index.find (*si);
       if (f==index.end())
       {
          ++index[*si];
          result.push_back(*si);
          ++si;
       }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: duplicates is not a good name for vector that only contains unique elements

Comment: @Kapil and not even necessary.

Answer (score 1):

After going through Spencer updated answer i don't think we require map altogether provided our objective is only to remove duplicates from string. Here is my solution with only std::string

```
string removeDuplicatesKeepingOriginalOrder(string const& s)
{
    string result;
    for(std::size_t i=0;i<s.size();i++)
    {
        if(result.find(s[i]) == std::string::npos)
        {
            result.push_back(s[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It all depends on how many possible different values there are. `std::string::find` has complexity O(n) and `std::map::find` has complexity O(log(n)). Try to think beyond the basic example.